# Vaadin 6 issue with upload button

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin6

We are using Vaadin 6 Upload Button. We observed that the button is buggy when uploading same file again and again or uploading a huge file. We have set it in immediate mode so we expected the browse button and textfield to be hidden. If we upload a fairly huge file the browse button and text field become visible leadin to confusion with users. Even their demo website is facing the same issue

To reproduce the issue:

1. Go to [Vaadin 6 Demo Immediate Upload](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ImmediateUpload)
2. Upload a fairly large file
3. You will observe that the browse button and text file become visible
   [image]
   How do we fix this? Vaadin has supposedly closed this [bug](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/7914#no2) with resolution as Not reproducible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fairly large file". Please be more specific. 5mb, 100mb, 1gb?

Comment: we observed this issue with even small files and when the user double clicked to upload?

Comment: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12246

Comment: Vaadin seems to have resolved this in vaadin 7 but have provided no workaround for vaadin 6